# Im getting "The server encountered an error and could not complete your request" error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encoding

Im getting "The server encountered an error and could not complete your request" error in my google app engine:

my app.yaml:

```
application: myapp
version: 2
runtime: python
api_version: 1

builtins:
- remote_api: on
- datastore_admin: on

handlers:
- url: /AJAX
  script: main.py

- url: /emailtrigger
  script: main.py

- url: /emailworker
  script: main.py

- url: /
  static_files: static_files/index.html
  upload: static_files

- url: /
  static_dir: static_files
```

error in log:

```
<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file /base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.349019521625775975/main.py on line 77, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (main.py, line 77)
```

I have a string with a character: ã;
the main.py is utf-8 encoded

Comment: Not even close to enough information. For example: what specifically is the request that you are making that is failing? Are you seeing this on the local development server or in production? Is there an error message in the log?

Comment: its a generic post request that works locally and not in development. log error i've posted in question.

Comment: Did you read PEP-263 and follow its instructions?

Comment: i dont know, this is latin? i think i can use: #!/usr/bin/python
          # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

is right?

Comment: latin-1 is not the same thing as utf-8. If the file is encoded in utf-8, use "coding: utf-8".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to receive variables in a post in google app engine that contains string with chars like: õ á?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316188/how-to-receive-variables-in-a-post-in-google-app-engine-that-contains-string-with)

Comment: That's three variations of the same question you've posted now. Can you please just put all the information in one question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. try adding this as first line of your code

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

1. try coverting your strings to unicode

   self.response.out.write(unicode("ã","UTF-8"))

Comment: are you sure? because                                                        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                was the original text of my post.stars had gone missing after I submitted it. :/ anyway glad to hear that it worked.

Comment: i still dont know why.. i had then another problem, check my other question. i should be put "u" before a string that contains "ã". GAE is strange.