# How to receive variables in a post in google app engine that contains string with chars like: õ á?

Tags: google-app-engine, encoding, decoding

```
email = self.request.get('email')
name = self.request.get('name')
mail.send_mail(sender="myemail", email=email, body=name, subject="sss " + name + "sdafsaã")
```

// added ã: the problem was that "sdafsaã" should be u"sdafsaã". with a "u" before the string. and now it works

then i get this

```
main.py", line 85, in post

subject="sss " + name + "sdafsa",
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 36: ordinal not in range(128)
```

the might have chars like õ ó and something like that.

for more details:

the code to run the worker(the code before)
the name is the one that is received from the datastore and contains chars like õ and ó...

```
 taskqueue.add(url='/emailworker', params={'email': e.email, 'name': e.name})
```

thanks

Comment: Are you using python 2.5 (not 2.6+) on the dev server?

Comment: Edit the original, don't re-ask the same question differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading a little about how unicode works in Python:

- [Dive Into Python - Unicode](http://diveintopython.net/xml_processing/unicode.html)
- [Unicode In Python, Completely Demystified](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Also, make sure you're running Python 2.5 if you are seeing this error on the development server.

Comment: the problem is joining 2 strings: ||| body = name + "ã" => error ||| body = name + u"ã" => works!!! |||

Comment: Try working solely with unicode strings as long as possible (so `decode()` your ASCII strings to unicode ones) and then `encode()` the unicode back to a byte-string when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
email = self.request.get('email')
name = self.request.get('name')
mail.send_mail(sender="myemail", 
               email=email, 
               body=name, 
               subject="hello " + name.encode('utf-8') + " user!")
```

The variable `name` is a unicode string and should encoded in `utf-8` or in the kind of encode you are using in you web application before concatenating to other byte strings.
Without `name.encode()`, Python uses the default 7 bits `ascii` codec  that can't encode that specific character.

Comment: thanks but the problem was not there; i should be added the "u" before a string that contains "ã". that was all

Answer (score 0):

the problem is joining 2 strings: ||| body = name + "ã" => error ||| body = name + u"ã" => works!!! |||

Answer (score 0):

Try with `encode`

```
t ='việt ứng '
m = MyModel()
m.data = t.encode('utf-8')
m.put() #success!
```